# Velocity: how to partially parse html template?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, velocity

Is it possible in Apache's velocity template engine to partially parse html template?

For example:

If I have template like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="section1">Some content of section 1....</div>
    <div id="section2">Some content of section 2....</div>
</div>
```

I would like to parse only contents of section1 div. How can I accomplish this?

I'm using Spring MVC 3.0 with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to achieve this, but you can use variables to define parts and assist in partial parsing:

```
<div class="container">
 #if ($model.part1) 
    <div id="section1">Some content of section 1....</div>
 #end
 #if (model.part2) 
    <div id="section2">Some content of section 2....</div>
 #end
</div>
```

where model

```
public class PartialDef {
boolean part1;
boolean part2;
//setters and getters
}
```

So based on which part of html you want to include/exclude, define and turn-On/Off variables accordingly.